# WordPress: cannot access callback_args key values inside callback function

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I am developing a simple plugin based custom post type. The post type is registered fine. Now I want to create some meta boxes and pass a few property values via callback arguments. This is what I tried:

```
function wpcd_add_dealer_meta_boxes() {
        add_meta_box(
            'dealer_first_name',
            'First Name',
            array($this, 'wpcd_meta_box_first_name_markup'),
            'dealers',
            'normal',
            'default',
            array(
                'id' => 'first_name',
                'name' => 'first_name',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter first name',
                'maxlength' => '30',
                'spellcheck' => 'true',
                'autocomplete' => 'off'
            )
        );
    }
```

And here is my callback function with an argument:

```
function wpcd_meta_box_first_name_markup($args) {
        $html = '<input ';
        $html.= 'type="' . $args->type . '" ';
        $html.= 'id="' .$args->id . '" ';
        $html.= 'name="' .$args->name . '" ';
        if( isset($args->required) && ($args->required == 'true' || $args->required == '1' ) ) {
            $html.= 'required ';
        }

        if( isset($args->placeholder) && $args->placeholder != '' ) {
            $html.= 'placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args->placeholder ) . '" ';
        }

        if( isset($args->maxlength) ) {
            $html.= 'maxlength="' . $args->maxlength . '" ';
        }

        if( isset($args->spellcheck) && ($args->spellcheck == 'true' ) ) {
            $html.= 'spellcheck="' . $args->spellcheck . '" ';
        }

        if( isset($args->autocomplete) && ($args->autocomplete == 'on' ) ) {
            $html.= 'autocomplete="' . $args->autocomplete . '" ';
        }

        $html.= '/>';

        echo $html;
    }
```

But I cannot get the values like `$args->id, $args->name` etc inside the function. To be precise, all the values are empty, where I did not check `if(isset(...))`. And where I did those are simply ignored.

With my above code I am expecting the following markup as output:

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="last_name" required placeholder="Enter firstname" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" />
```

while the actual output is

```
<input type="" id="" name="" />
```

Attributes `type`, `id` and `name` are not wrapped inside an `if(isset())` block so they are being generated (with empty values) and whatever is wrapped inside `if(isset())` block, are simply being ignored, as if they are not set at all!

What I am missing or doing wrong?
Any suggestion would be a life saver for me.

Comment: What about using `$args['type']` etc. ?

Comment: Indeed. You're putting values in an array and using object access syntax to try and get them out.

Comment: @Und3rTow I tried `$args['type']` already and got this:

`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in /var/www/wp-projects/subratasarkar.com/wp-content/plugins/product-dealer/product-dealer.php on line 68`

@MattGibson would you please tell me the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for `add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) carefully, you'll see:

> ($callback_args (array) (Optional)  Data that should be set as the
>   $args property of the box array (which is the **second** parameter passed
>   to your callback).

The *first* parameter passed to your callback is a `WP_Post` object. The *second* is your parameter array. So, try:

```
function wpcd_meta_box_first_name_markup($post, $args) { ...
```

And then access your arguments as you'd expect:

```
$args['type']
```

Comment: Yes, I got it working finally. I was missing the first parameter `$post`. And then using var_dump I understood how the array has been formed. Sorry for trouble sir. Thank you very much for looking into it.